# celery + redis + flask how to get the quantity of jobs await to execute by celery

Tags: flask, redis, docker-compose, celery

I use docker to run celery + redis + flask, and I want to know how many tasks is waiting to be executed by celery. I tried to find the information in redis with command

```
keys *
```

and I get result:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "unacked_mutex"
2) "_kombu.binding.celeryev"
3) "unacked_index"
4) "_kombu.binding.celery.pidbox"
5) "_kombu.binding.celery"
6) "unacked"
```

Non of these items seem to contain the celery queue information. How can I read the celery queue size?

This is the celery code:

```
from celery import Celery
import time
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://redis:6379')
@app.task
def sleeptest():
    time.sleep(100)
```

This is how I submit the celery job:

```
import tasks
import time

tasks.sleeptest.delay()
time.sleep(1)
tasks.sleeptest.delay()
time.sleep(1)
tasks.sleeptest.delay()
time.sleep(1)
tasks.sleeptest.delay()
time.sleep(1)
tasks.sleeptest.delay()
time.sleep(1)
```

When I post 100 tasks, the celery queue occurs. But when I post only 5 tasks, the celery queue donnot show, even though I set concurrency to 1 and 4 tasks is actually awaiting.

Comment: Check out http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#monitoring-redis-queues and https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1272

Comment: I've checked this out, but still cannot solve my problem

Comment: When I post 100 tasks, the celery queue occurs. But when I post only 5 tasks, the celery queue donnot show, even though I set concurrency to 1 and 4 tasks is actually awaiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is buried deep in the Celery documentation - [monitoring redis queues](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#monitoring-redis-queues). If you see nothing, that means that the tasks are either finished, running or already reserved (look for details about the [worker_prefetch_multiplier](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#worker-prefetch-multiplier)).

Comment: Thanks, this explains.